# jQuery animate scrollTop not working with anchor links in Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, anchor, scrolltop

I have scrolling div with anchor links at top to jump to certain parts of div with a button to scroll back to top. Using jquery it returns to top of page just fine but in chrome, not so much. In chrome, if you use the anchor links to jump to "#target" and then click to return to top of page, it scrolls up, then jumps back down to the previously clicked on target anchor. Interestingly enough, if you manually scroll down (not using a target link), the scrollTop will work just fine. Can someone help me figure out what is going on here?

HTML:

```
<a href="#target1">Link 1</a>
<a href="#target2">Link 2</a>
<a href="#target3">Link 3</a>

...more HTML stuff here...

<div id="this_div">
<a name="target1"></a>
<a name="target2"></a>
<a name="target3"></a>
</div>
<div id="topbutton">TOP</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#topbutton').click(function(){
$('#this_div').animate({scrollTop: 0}, "fast"});
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, I'll go ahead and answer my own question. WTFE.

Clear out the hash, problem solved.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#topbutton').click(function(){
        location.hash='';
        $('#br_content').animate({scrollTop: 0}, "medium");
    });
});
```